Excel use formula within a reference
I have a formula that references and external workbook on onedrive that looks like this
='[2024 orders.xlsx]JAN'!$A$2

What i want to do is dynamically substitute the year ('2024') based on another worksheet and sell, say config!a1
So im thinking something like below, but obviously this doesnt work, or i wouldnt be asking:
='[concat(config!a1, " orders.xlsx")]JAN'!$A$2

any help is appareciated

https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+indirect+external+workbook+site:stackoverflow.com

thanks @BigBen, the second search result provided an answer that worked:  =INDIRECT("'[" & config!A1 & " orders.xlsx]JAN'!$A$2")

Note that the linked workbook must be open.

that sucks. im thinking maybe powerquery is an option to not have it open
